# Simultaneous animations on Raphael objects - Last animation overrides previous animations of the object

Tags: animation, raphael

I'm trying to rotate and revolve a Raphael shape simultaneously. Here's what I've tried (100,100 is the center of canvas):

```
var revolve = Raphael.animation({transform: 'r360,100,100'},1000,"easein")
var rotate = Raphael.animation({transform: 'r360'},1000,"linear")
var ec = paper.ellipse(100,50,10,5).attr({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: 'blue'
})
```

And the variety of ways I've tried to call the animation, each producing the described result:

1. second animation is overriding the first one:

   ```
   ec.animate(revolve).animate(rotate)
   ```
2. works fine but with some issues (metioned below):

   ```
   ec.animate({
       transform: 'r360,100,100r360'
   }, 1000, "easein")
   ```
3. second animation is overriding the first one, again:

   ```
   ec.animate({
       transform: 'r360,100,100'
   }, 1000, "easein")
   .animate({
       transform: 'r360'
   }, 1000, "easein")
   ```

*** The problem with the second variation is that i cant vary the easing function for rotate and revolve separately. In addition, the `transform:'...r360'` is not working (overriding the first animation).

Here's a [working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFhZD/) for you to mess around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of achieving that, apparently. To prove it you can chain both animations while using a delay on the second, and pass it with various values around 1000 (above and below). You'll see the animation renderer is serial:

```js
ec.animate(revolve)
ec.animate(rotate.delay(/*200*/1000));
```

In order for them to work simultaneously, you'd have to fit both transitions into one transition-string and pass it to a single animation object, much like you did on the second variation in your attempts (it seems there's no real problem with it besides the limitation to define a different easing for each animation):

```js
var revolveAndRotate = Raphael.animation({
    transform: 'r360,100,100r360'
}, 1000, "easein")

ec.animate(revolveAndRotate);​
```

​​​​
Here's the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/YFhZD/3/) to demonstrate it.

Comment: In this fiddle the rotation is not performing. In order to know whether the rotation is occuring or not, i have made the rotation degrees to 90 so on completion of a revolution, the eclipse will be in standing position. but only revolve is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/tvC2E/) what you're looking for? I've added a second rotation to the revolve animation, rotating 360 degrees in the opposite direction. The second animation, rotate, is obsolete.

```
var revolve = Raphael.animation({transform:'r360,100,100 r-360'},1000,"easein")
```

Comment: The eclipse is performing rotation only.

Comment: Sorry. Saved a previous version of the fiddle. Try it again.

Comment: I have replaced the code in the fiddle with the above code.please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/tvC2E/2/, its doing rotate and revolve. is it possible to do those actions in different easing function.

Comment: I really should have read your question before throwing out an answer :( I can see now you had already come up with a similar solution. Having said that, I'm still unsure as to what your issue is. Have you tried putting in a different easing function? I've tried "bounce" on your fiddle and it worked as expected. (http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/VXKTf/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way of doing it and even go far behond it.

Remember raphael is all about paths and hierarchy. As for 3D softwares it is all about keeping the highest level of hierarchy with paths follows in order to have the most complex animations as possible and keep one "transform" function for each hierarchy level..

In order to achieve such chained animations, and keep the first hierarchy animation ( transform ) as the first animation hierarchy, a good trick used in 3D world is to use paths "dummies".

**In your case the dummy to achieve rotation is a circle path with a radius of zero.**

- level 1 : The elipse has his own transforms animations.
- level 2 : the elipse rotate 360 around a circle path that has a zero
  radius ( making it rotating around himself ) + the dummy can have his own transform.
- level 3 : the dummy use the revolve function or path follow another circle dummy path that have a radius of 100 ( and his own transform )

In addition to Using  transition strings as an intermediate hierarchy level, "dummies" as paths, will allows you to chain, at will, any kind of animations, keeping 1 primitive tranform function for each hierarchy level.

Circle path with a radius of zero is the most used dummy is 3D world.

Once you have chained your dummies animations, trigger each animation with timing functions for each dummy. It is done the exact same way in keyframing softwares.